# How to mint multiple NFT for CMV3 using UMI

Tags: metaplex, umi

I’m updating my candy machine to UMI method as to utilize minting pNft and was wondering how I could mint multiple in 1 click.

I combed through the docs and didn’t see anything. There is a two hundred and twenty character limit to post. Thank you in advance.